# azure devops run build pipelines sequentially

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Whenever multiple builds are running on the same pipeline only the first build completes and the rest error.

I would the builds to run sequentially instead of in parallel like they are now, so that if two developers check-in at about the same time, the second build will also complete.

When editing the pipeline in the execution plan under the Parallelism heading I have the radio button set to "none" and they still seem to try to run in parallel anyway.

> Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pe76.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have multiple build agents. Assuming you are using self-hosted build agents, you could specify certain **demands** of the agent to use only one agent. In this way, if the agent is not free, the build will keep waiting. To use a particular agent, add a demand of `Agent.Name equals agentname`, check the screenshot below. Agent name can be found in **capabilities** of the agent.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I needed to do. Thanks Cece Dong